# How to track the users who installed our app in android

Tags: google-play

is there a way we can keep track of users who installed our app, and when the user uninstalls we should get response too that particular user uninstalled..how Android market place keeps a track of uninstalled applications?

Answer (score 1):

Developer Account has a dashboard from where you can find  how many active installs are there .
For Google it is easy to keep track of uninstalled applications because  all the apps you download from it are associated with a gmail acccount and whenever you visit market they list updates according to that.

If you want to track the install and uninstall you can have your own app activation/registration module like many other apps out there . I am not sure how you will be able to track uninstall though .